# ConfigurationErrorsException: 'Configuration system failed to initialize'

Tags: windows, vb.net

The code is as follows and posted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/developing-apps/programming/app-settings/how-to-create-property-grids-for-user-settings).

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class dlgSettings
    Private Sub dlgSettings_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        PropertyGrid1.SelectedObject = My.Settings
        ' Attribute for the user-scope settings.
        Dim userAttr As New System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute
        Dim attrs As New System.ComponentModel.AttributeCollection(userAttr)
        PropertyGrid1.BrowsableAttributes = attrs

    End Sub
End Class
```

The error is from Settings.Designer.vb generated code:

```
<Global.System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute(),  _
Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(),  _
Global.System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("SPACE ONLY")>  _
Public ReadOnly Property DefaultCircuitDescription() As String
    Get
        Return CType(Me("DefaultCircuitDescription"),String)
    End Get
End Property
```

The error reads:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: 'Configuration system failed to initialize'
```

Comment: What framework are you targeting? I don't know whether it's been fixed but I believe that there's an issue with the auto-generated config file in .NET Core projects.

Comment: I'm using .NET 5.0